# Serilog Dispose/Close log file-stream

Tags: c#, logging, stream, serilog

Recently I focused in `Serilog` to point out a templated path based on the current Date of every `LogEvent`.
After figuring how to implement this, I finally resolve the path on the fly by using the Date field into `LogEvent` by using `Serilog.Sinks.Map`, such as shown below:

```
return new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo
    .Map(
        // Log key
        (LogEvent le) => le.Timestamp.Date,
        // Log Action
        (DateTime date, LoggerSinkConfiguration lc) =>
        {
            string path = GetFilesPath(date, logName);
            lc.File(path);
        }
    );
```

```
public string GetFilePath(DateTime date, string logName) =>
            Path.Combine("./Logs", $"{date:yyyy-MM-dd}", $"{logName}.log");
```

With this, I achieved my goal: writing logs with in a sub folder based on the Date.

The issue is, since `Serilog` does not know that the pointing path changed, it does not close or dispose the file stream as expected. So, my application leaves files opened day to day, ad infinitum.

It'd be great if someone has faced this approach, to manually close the stream, or if `Serilog` API exposes somehow automatically close those streams.

Btw, I am using

- Serilog 2.9.0
- Serilog.Sinks.File 4.1.0
- Serilog.Sinks.Map 1.0.1

**Edit 05/06/2020** for those reading this afterwards.
Keying every single log event by the *Timestamp* is a bad idea. By doing so, we are in fact adding an entry per log event (supposing that no events are being emitted at the same time, for simplicity).
Even if we specify the `sinkMapCountLimit` to `0`, which in theory won't keep any event in our map, if that event is configured to write to file (specially with the `RollingFile` sink), those sinks won't be disposed nor erased from memory.

So, the chunk of code above is leaking memory (and pretty fast).
The [`Map.Sink` documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map) warns about this, indeed.

> ...but isn't suitable when the set of possible key values is open-ended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Serilog.Sinks.Map* accepts a parameter `sinkMapCountLimit` to control this:

```
return new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo
    .Map(
        // Log key
        (LogEvent le) => le.Timestamp.Date,
        // Log Action
        (DateTime date, LoggerSinkConfiguration lc) =>
        {
            string path = GetFilesPath(date, logName);
            lc.File(path);
        },
        sinkMapCountLimit: 5
    );
```

Comment: Sure, @Nicholas That is what I was looking for. After some research, I cannot understand the real impact of keeping only a few sinks open, or none. I set this parameter to `0` and run my logger down to a kind of stress test and everthing seems OK. Is this parameter taking part elsewhere?

Comment: Here's where the parameter is used: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.Map/Sinks/Map/MappedSink%601.cs#L58 - HTH

Comment: As I can see, the only difference is that sinks are disposed when the sink count is greater that the limit. If the sink limit is 0, every sink instance must be created to actually emit the event... Well, this is a trade off I can afford. **Thanks** for the point. Very useful.